# Wordpress Admin Post Type Table Class Filter Hook

Tags: plugin-development

So I've looked all through the documentation to see if I can find a filter hook of some sort to add an extra class name to the Wordpress/WooCommerce (CPT) post table in the backend. There must be a way somewhere, as WooCommerce adds on "status-wc-" into the html class.

Anyone able to help me out and point me in the right direction?

[image: WooCommerce Custom Post Type]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `get_post_class()` is [used to generate these classes](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/16371b99d8e5111dcc83b8961b4d68681e82d25e/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L1184). You can filter `post_class` to change the output.

Example

```
is_admin() && add_filter( 'post_class', function( $classes, $class, $post_id ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    // Decide whether to add a class or not …

    $classes[] = 'my-custom-class';

    return $classes;    
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: You sir, are a legend! You don't realise how long i was looking for that through the documentation.

Comment: @JamesSimpson Never rely on external documentation, just look at the source code. I have now added a link to that code to my answer.